# A step in Danilov's book on Algebraic varieties and schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand a step in V. I. Danilov's book on Algebraic varieties and schemes [1, fourth paragraph of Section 5.4 in Chapter II (page 232)].

> Let $Y$ be a complex affine variety and $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n \times Y$ a closed subvariety. Suppose that the projection $f : X \to Y$ is unramified at $x \in X$. Then, locally near $x$, we may assume that $X$ lies in $\mathbb{A}^1 \times Y$.

The reason given is that we can do this "by choosing an appropriate projection $\mathbb{A}^n \to \mathbb{A}^1$". Could someone help me understand that? There is also the assumption that $f$ is finite, although I don't know if it is used at this step.

**References**

[1] Danilov, V. I. Algebraic varieties and schemes. Algebraic geometry, I, 167–297, Encyclopaedia Math. Sci., 23, Springer, Berlin, 1994.

Comment: This follows from the precise version of the Noether Normalization Theorem given in Eisenbud's "Commutative algebra."  At a more informal level, it follows from basically the same proof as the Primitive Element Theorem: the function field of $X$ is generated as a field extension of the function field of $Y$ by a single element $g$ (and that element gives the rational function to $\mathbb{A}^1$).